# Sheet shows formula instead of result while displaying content of one sheet to another

Tags: excel, apache-poi

I need to display Excel sheet content to another sheet in same Excel file. Here I have two sheet `MATHS` and `RESULT`. I tried to set a cell value of `RESULT` by using `=MATHS!D5` or `='MATHS'!D5`.  (I tried these two formulas.)

I got formula `=MATHS!D5` or `='MATHS'!D5` instead of the result in the cell.

The **calculation option** is **Automatic** and cells are not **Text**, it shows **General**.

When open, Excel shows:

[image]

Double click on the cells the result appears:

[image]

Comment: How you are putting the formula into the cell in apache-poi? Hint: Use `setCellFormula(java.lang.String formula)` instead of `setCellValue(java.lang.String value)`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to use

```
.setCellFormula("'MATHS'!D5");
```

to display the values of different sheet.

if it displays ='MATHS'!D5 you might have used

```
.setCellValue("='MATHS'!D5");
```

Hope it rings a bell.

Comment: your right it's working correctly i have been using setCellValue instead of setCellFormula and    i put  "=" symbol infront of the formula.